# Correcting equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation which goes like this:

```
a = (1-b)*(teta-90)*(3.14/180)
```

This is a text from the book, which goes along with this equation:

```
This is a simple straight line which has the property of being equal to 0 when teta = 90 degrees and equal
to 1 - b when teta = 60 degrees.
```

I understand that when teta = 90:

```
a = (1-b)*(90-90)*(3.14/180)
a = (1-b)*0*(3.14/180)
a = 0
```

But when `teta = 60`, `a = 1-b` is not correct.
It looks that the upper equation is not correct.

How would a corrected equation look like, so that `a = 1-b` for `teta = 60`?

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure the angle should be spelled "theta". [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1-b)\cdot(\theta-90)\cdot\frac{x}{180}=1-b \overset{\theta=60}{\Rightarrow } (1-b) (60-90) \cdot \frac{x}{180}=1-b \Rightarrow -30 \cdot \frac{x}{180}=1 \Rightarrow x=-\frac{180}{30}=-6 $$

So if you have the following equation:

$$a = (1-b) \cdot (\theta-90)\cdot \frac{-6}{180}$$

it holds that for $\theta=60$, $a=1-b$.

Comment: Thank you evinda.
Looks like the initial `a` equation was wrongly written in the documentation which is my source.
I appreciate your effort.